# Just using the Browser bundle, how can I send a transaction (ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined)?

Tags: transactions, javascript, web3.js, buffer, html

I've been messing around for a while with the @solana/web3.js browser bundle (https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/javascript-api#bundle) and I'm having some difficulty sending a transaction. My current code utilizes the `sendAndConfirmTransaction` method, but I'm seeing the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at toBufferLE (browser.js:48:24)
    at bigIntLayout.encode (bigint.ts:30:19)
    at Structure.encode (Layout.js:1092:36)
    at encodeData (instruction.ts:32:15)
    at SystemProgram.transfer (system.ts:796:14)
    at sendTransaction ((index):88:36)
    at async Proxy.submitData ((index):65:9)
```

Below is the function I'm currently working with.

```
async function sendTransaction() {
  console.log('Sending transaction...')
  try {
    const keypair = await solanaWeb3.Keypair;
    let transaction = new solanaWeb3.Transaction();
    let connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"));

    transaction.add(
      solanaWeb3.SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
        toPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
        lamports: solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
      }),
    );
    solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [keypair]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

I've read that Buffer is not available in the latest builds of the web3.js library, but the only answers I've seen are related to Webpack updates. I'm assuming I'm missing a dependency? Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Buffer` is available in Node.js runtimes, but not in browsers.

Without knowing the exact shape of your build system I can only give general advice, which is that you'll need to install a `Buffer` polyfill like https://github.com/feross/buffer.

We're actively looking to [eliminate](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/27590) `Buffer` from `@solana/web3.js` completely.

Comment: I'll give that a shot! What's the timeline on fully eliminating `Buffer` from the library?

Comment: I can't promise anything more than: Stay Tuned™.

Comment: Circling back to this, I'm not able to find a way to load Buffer using just inline HTML. From what I'm seeing it looks like I would have to use `npm` or `yarn` to install the `Buffer` polyfill. Am I officially stuck until `Buffer` is removed from `@solana/web3.js`?

Comment: You could try some abomination like this, @jeffersonbenson, but really the solution is to build your own polyfill. Relying on others' CDNs is extremely dangerous and can rely on loss of funds. https://jsbin.com/quzewiticu/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Good point there @steveluscher. Ultimately I think the answer is there currently is no solution utilizing just the browser bundle to send a transaction to a program. This does kinda shift my project's architecture, but definitely will be helpful in the long run :)